# Module Description for web project

Tags: java, project

If i want to make web project like slideshare in java, what can be my Module description?I don't want whole description just show me the direction from where i can start.

@Robin Green: Can these be my Module description

[image: Mod Desc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the description in the Maven `pom.xml` file, this can be anything you like. It is only for documentation purposes. So just put some brief description of what the project does.

Comment: I have added my module desc, please take a look at it

Comment: well if you wrote some text to describe what it is happening in that diagram, you could use that text, sure. But like I said, it could be anything, it's only for you and your fellow software developers to read.

Comment: Do you know any sites where i can see some example

Comment: if you Google `pom.xml description` you'll probably find some eventually. Here's [one I found](https://java.net/projects/noorm/sources/src/content/pom.xml)

Comment: By the way, as this is a web application, not a library, the only purpose of the description would be to tell another developer what this web application actually does, which is usually obvious if you just run it or read its code. So some people don't bother to put a description for web applications.